# How to add z-index on before?

Tags: html, css

Every div should have an arrow. I want something like this:
[image: four horizontally arranged blocks. Each, except the last, has a wedge on the right hand side]

Any suggestions on how can I do that?

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #008000;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-right: none;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-right: -5px;
}

div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  background-color: #008000;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-14px, -7px);
}
```

```html
<div>arrow with border</div>
<div>arrow with border</div>
<div>arrow with border</div>
```

Comment: in fact, you need to add the before to the left of your divs with left: 0%;, and not to the right, and just ignore the first ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```css
ul {
    margin: 20px 60px;
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 5px 1px 0 0;
    text-indent: 35px;
    position: relative;
}

ul li:before {
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: -2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 0 15px 15px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent white;
    z-index: 0;
}

ul li:first-child:before {
    border-color: transparent;
}

ul li a:after {
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: -15px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 0 15px 15px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent darkgray;
    z-index: 10;
}

ul li.active a {
    background: green;
    z-index: 100;
}

ul li.active a:after {
    border-left-color: green;
}

ul li a {
    display: block;
    background: darkgray;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a:hover {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}

ul li a:hover:after {
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Foobar</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Foobar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Foobar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Foobar</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer. What did you change? Why should it solve the problem?

Comment: @Quentin could you find 5?

Comment: this i what i need ... tnx

Answer (score 0):

In order to the arrow appear above the items you will need to use `z-index > 0`.
In order to position the arrow in the right place, I've added `padding & margin` to each `li`.

To not render the arrow for the last item, I've used the `sibling selector` (+), so the first `li` won't get arrow.

Something like that

```css
ul {
  display: block;
  background: gray;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

li + li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: -3px;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-14px, -7px);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>menu 1</li>
  <li>menu 2</li>
  <li>menu 3</li>
  <li>menu 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer. What did you change? Why should it solve the problem?

Comment: `li + li:before` is not very user friendly, but i know the :not(first-child) does not work in all cases, just explain it simply ignores first `li` of the `ul`

Comment: "In order to the arrow appear above the items you will need to use z-index > 0" — But the code in the question already does!

Comment: He put `z-index > 0` on the div itself, instead of on the `before`

Comment: @Neil, 'li + li:before is not very user friendly', why?

Comment: @FelixMosheev it is, just that you didn't explained it in your cado at the time :) actually you have the most detailed answer.

Answer (score -1):

Here is simple example of steps Try one of these links.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/qXCed/5/
```

```css
nav {
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
    float: left;
}
ul li {
    float: right;
    text-indent: 25px;
}
ul li:last-child {
    margin-left: -15px;
}
ul li a {
    background: #ddd;
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, @start_color, @end_color);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, from(#fff), to(#ccc));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left top, #eee 38%, #ddd 61%);
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: block;
    line-height: 12px;
    margin-top: -33px;
    padding: 40px 0;
    width: 92px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
ul li a:hover {
    background: #ddd;
    background-image: none;
}
ul li a span {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Current</li>
        <li><a href="#3"><span>Third</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#2"><span>Second</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#1"><span>First</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```